# Função equivalente ao Chr$ no C#

Tags: c#, .net, string, visual-basic-6, char

Estou migrando um trecho de código em Visual Basic 6 e me deparei com a seguinte chamada:

```
variavel = Chr$(27) & Chr(15)
```

1 - Qual seriam as funções equivalente no C#?

2 - Qual a diferença entre `Chr$` e `Chr`?

Comment: Em VB.NET: colocar o `$` no final da variável/função converte explicitamente o valor dela para uma `String`. Assim funciona com o `%` para `Integer` também, `&` para `Double`, etc. Não sei se estes outros caracteres funcionam no VB6.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Basta fazer um *cast* do número para `char`, algo assim:

```
(char)27
```

Mas provavelmente deveria fazer alguma coisa diferente, a semântica da linguagem muda então não costuma ser só traduzir uma expressão, deve ter outra forma de fazer isso em C#, quem sabe até mesmo em VB6 já era errado fazer isto. Um dos motivos que acho isto é que não faz sentido usar as duas formas da função `chr()`, uma que retorna `String` e outra que retorna uma `Variant`.

Em C# provavelmente usar isto:

```
"\u0027\u0015"
```

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/CSharp/Cast/StringEsc.cs).

Comment: Complementando: o `Asc()` é o contrário da operação: `(int)'c'`.